# Parse rdf/xml file with php?

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

Here's my issue...

I have a mysql table full of library records. The have all the usual info for a book (title, date of publication, author, etc)...plus one field that is the URL for a library link to the book. If you append to the end of the URL, you can get the info in different formats (mrc, ris, endnote, rdf, xml). It looks like xml is the easiest to work with:

```
http://mirlyn.lib.umich.edu/Record/004032026.rdf
```

The issue with the table is that it was largely done by hand and has many inconsistencies. I would like to update the table using the rdf files. How can I parse this thing in PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) It's not that XML parsing with PHP would be a completely exotic thing to do. There's a *massive* body of examples on the Internet, please try something first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used simplexml. Had trouble getting Magpie to work. Simplexml was...simple!:)

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel - for example, you can use the [Magpie RSS Library](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) for PHP.

You can use the data you load from the rdf feed to update your database.

Comment: after downloading and unpacking the magpierss, what do i do with that folder? i'm new to php. the readme file doesn't what to do. thanks!